# Create a new repo with only certain versions

Tags: git, version-control

I've an existing git repo (`existingrepo`). Now I want to create a *new* git repo (`newrepo`) that will contain only certain tagged/release versions.

For example,

```
existingrepo v0.1
existingrepo v0.2
existingrepo v1.0 
existingrepo v1.1
existingrepo v1.2
existingrepo v1.3 
existingrepo v2.0

newrepo    v1.0
newrepo    v2.0
```

What is the recommended way for achieving this in git?

Comment: Create `newrepo` by cloning `existingrepo` and, in the clone, use interactive rebase to only keep the commits of interest.

Comment: @Jubobs A better approach might be to loop over all the versions (presumably tags), use `git archive` to create a zip/tar-file of that version that you then unpack into `newrepo` and commit with an appropriate commit message. I'd hate to have to use interactive rebase to select a dozen commits out of a thousand, and squash all the rest...

Comment: @twalberg I wouldn't know about that. I agree that, with a large total number of commits, my approach may prove unwieldy; however, if you use a good text editor and the number of commits to keep is small, it should be no hassle.

Answer (score 2):

I would take this approach, assuming all versions you are interested in have associated tags:

```
cd existingrepo
for v in $(<list_of_versions.txt)
do
  git archive --format=tar "refs/tags/${v}" | (cd newrepo; git rm -rf *; tar xpf -)
  (cd newrepo; git add -A .; git commit -m "Import of version ${v}"; git tag "${v}")
done
```